# Flexbox For Equal height columns and row (equalizer)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to use flexbox for this kind of patterns(see image attached) like

```
Box 1 height == (height of box 2 + height of box 3)
```

It is more like foundation equalizer, where change in height variation in either of the three boxes will adjust the boxes height and always look like the image[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can basically create a *nested flexbox* - the `box 1` and the `box 2 & 3 wrapper` in a *row* flexbox and `box 2 & 3` in a *column* flexbox.

Note the usage of `flex: 1` specifically - this allows equal heights as you desire.

See demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper > * {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
}
.wrapper > .box-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrapper > .box-wrap > .box {
  flex:1;
  margin: 5px;
}
.wrapper > .box-wrap > .box:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.wrapper > .box-wrap > .box:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    Some text here some text here some text here some text here Some text here some text here some text here some text here Some text here some text here some text here some text here Some text here some text here some text here some text here
  </div>
  <div class="box-wrap">
    <div class="box">
      Some text here
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Some text here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks For the answer. It is working good. Is it possible to have equal height boxes for box2 and box3.

Comment: when you give `flex: 1` and there are *two* flex items they will get equal heights... if you don't want equal heights, you can apply `flex: 1` to the item that must fill the remaining space left by the others...

Comment: But right now, the inner container is having flex:1, but it is not having equal height, just try to increase the content in box 2 and see box 3 height is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide this layout in 2 columns and in second columns you can have 2 rows or more if needed.

Following `HTML` structure for this kind of layout:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col box">
      Column one content goes here...
  </div>
  <div class="col right-col">
    <div class="box">
      Box one content goes here...
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Box two content goes here...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Necessary CSS:**

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
}

.right-col {
  flex-basis: 66.67%;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
}

.box {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right-col {
  flex-basis: 66.67%;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.right-col .box + .box {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col box">
    Column one content goes here...
  </div>
  <div class="col right-col">
    <div class="box">
      Box one content goes here...
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Box two content goes here... Loremp ipsum dolor sit amet Loremp ipsum dolor sit amet Loremp ipsum dolor sit amet Loremp ipsum dolor sit amet Loremp ipsum dolor sit amet Loremp ipsum dolor sit amet 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **To the Downvoter:** Kindly leave a comment describing the reason of your downvote. It will be appreciated and will be helpful in making corrections in my answer.

Comment: thanks For the answer. It is working good. Is it possible to have equal height boxes for box2 and box3.

Comment: why do these guys downvote without commenting!! very frustrating... +1

Comment: @kukkuz Yes, I agree.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do it with Flex. Just place a outer **"DIV"** and provide it property

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">

 <div class="box-1">
  1
 </div>

 <div class="box-2">
     <div class="box-3">
      2
      </div> 
      <div class="box-4">
       3
      </div> 
 </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .row{
    display:flex;
    width:100%
  }
.box-1,.box-2,.box-3,.box-4{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:3px;
    padding:3px;
 }
.box-3,.box-4{
    width:95%;
 }
```

Keep an extra box to hold box 2 and 3

[**JS Fiddle for you**](https://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/w55kdao0/5/)

Comment: Why use `float`?? ... `flexbox` does this well on its own

Comment: @LGSon yes, flex can do it but i used float.